# How can I change the shell in Windows 98

Tags: shell, windows-98

How do I change the default Windows shell from explore.exe to my own custom shell in Windows 98?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit `%WINDIR%\system.ini` using a text editor (or use *msconfig.exe*). The default shell is defined in section `[boot]`, variable `shell`.

```
[boot]
shell=Explorer.exe
```

Comment: This is old school. On Windows 3.x, I hear a popular replacement was fileman.exe (File Manager), which reminds ppl of Total Commander.

Comment: Before I try to change it, how can I change it back if I don't like it?

Comment: @StackUnderflow: Just open the `system.ini` file in a text editor (such as Notepad) and make your changes. If necessary, you can boot in "DOS mode" by hitting F8 during boot, in which you'll have the `EDIT` text editor available. (`edit c:\windows\system.ini`) Alternatively, make a backup copy (say, `system.bak`), restore with `COPY`. IIRC *msconfig* will keep a backup automatically.

Comment: @surfasb: It actually was the [default file manager](http://i.imgur.com/2lF6e.png) program on Windows 3.x (and it was `winfile.exe`). [Have some more oldschool.](http://i.imgur.com/AnXyZ.png)

Comment: @grawity - Whaddya mean "old school". This is top tech, bleeding edge !!!

Comment: They should go back to the old school icons!!

Comment: @ldigas: [How](http://i.imgur.com/vdf7r.png) [about](http://i.imgur.com/ea4bj.png) [this](http://i.imgur.com/KFKD5.png), [then](http://i.imgur.com/rKNA9.png)?

Comment: @surfasb - They are http://charlie.amigaspirit.hu/temp/windows-1-vs-8.jpeg :)

Comment: @grawity - Yaaawning ... been there, done that ... keep going further back :))) (okey, I didn't actually use win3.0, was on DOS for a long time).

Comment: @ldigas: I can go forward and show pictures of a [baby Explorer.exe](http://i.imgur.com/tyXGD.png). (It's not a matter of having "been there"; it's just fun to go back "there" again.)

Comment: @grawity - Agree! and that thing was actually pretty usable ... it was third best after nc and pct[ools]. Ah, the good old days ... took me two days to install a sound card, but apart from that ... i practically did everything else faster :)))

Comment: Three if it was Ronald :/